# C# XML serialization

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I want simple XML as :

```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
>     <contacts>
>       <contact>   
>         <mobile>0555555555</mobile>
>         <home>4212566</home>
>         <office>45698752</office>    
>         <fax>090909</fax>  
>         <email>sdgdg@dgsdg.com</email>  
>       </contact> 
>       ................................
>       <contact>   
>         <mobile>0555555555</mobile>
>         <home>4212566</home>
>         <office>45698752</office>    
>         <fax>090909</fax>  
>         <email>sdgdg@dgsdg.com</email>  
>       </contact>
>     </contacts>
```

i used sample from [link text](http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=173)

all work fine but  there has some attributes such as  xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd.
i dont want to save it on my xml. and dont want to use Replace methods How do it?

I will use it in MVC Application. What is the best way to create an xml on memory? 
And look this post [link text](http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=173) when going to answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize your `XmlWriter` with an `XmlWriterSettings`, and set `XmlWriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration` to `true`:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true };
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
{
    // serialize XML here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To omit XML declaration **and** default XML namespaces:

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = true };

var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(file, settings))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(source.GetType());
    serializer.Serialize(writer, source, namespaces);
}
```